# Why does my Moto G 2nd gen show H and not LTE?

Tags: 4g

I just switched from T-Mobile to Cricket today, for 2 Android phones. One is my existing OnePlus One and it shows LTE next to the signal strength. The other is a (new) Moto G 2nd gen, which I read supports LTE but shows "H" next to the signal strength. And boy does it seem slow.
In addition, if I go to the Preferred Network Type in Settings, only 2G and 3G are listed. No LTE listed.
Is this correct or do I have a bad SIM?
Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd gen Moto G comes in a bunch of variants. The US models don't support LTE, only the Asia/EU ones do. You'll need to figure out what specific model you have (possibly in your device settings) then you can compare it to a list such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moto_G_(2nd_generation)

Comment: Wow, I never knew about the variants. I just Googled the specs before and it showed LTE without mention of this. OK well that explains it, thank you.